# Rest service contract - how to expose

Tags: java, spring, rest, service

When I write a soap service it is very easy to provide my clients a contract of what to expect from my service. How to call it, return types etc. 
This contract my clients can generated them self when they know the URL of my service and it is described in WSDL language.

What are best practices come rest ? For instance my newly created rest service has just 2 methods:

1) A ping service that needs NO request payload and just returns a plain string "OK" in the response body if it is up an running. 
That GET request from a browser looks like this http://localhost:8080/rest/ping). There are no request parameters nor a request body.

2) The second one is a create user service that needs a User object as input with a first name and last name as mandatory fields. 
It returns the newly created user back to client in the response body represented in json.

That POST request from postman can look like this: http://localhost:8080/weather/rest/weather/. 
It has no request parameters, but includes a request body, i.e "{"firstname":"john", "lastname":"smith"}". The string is represented as json in this example.
(does it need to be ? Are there better way to send "objects" to my service ?). Both these are mandatory and would like to tell my clients that somehow.

The response is the user sent back to the client and also includes a email address fields which my service has generated, in addition to the first name and last name provided.
It looks like this: {"firstname":"john", "lastname":"smith", "email":"john.smith@example.org"} and is in the response body. Again, are there better ways to return "objects" back to 
clients than representing them as json ?

So tl;dr: What's the best way to "expose" these services to my client without telling with words how to use it. 
AFAIK there are no WSDL contract or similar that are usually used when working with rest.

Thanks for your time. And hopefully this is a not a pure duplicate of some similar question.

Comment: Look up [Web Application Description Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language).

Answer (score 0):

It is very complex to answer in a correct way at this question because REST unlike SOAP is an architectural style and not a protocol. Many times you can find on internet that the rest-way for describe a rest ws is WADL([WADL on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)) and it works fine for "crud" rest-ws but in my opinion a better way is to use RSDL ([RSDL on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSDL)) because include some important aspect of a rest-ws as hypermedia links description http-hader definition used for uri and so on. Hovewer the key point hear is that rest isn't a framework or protocol, REST means embrace the web capability for build a loose coupled distributed system and even if you have a reach xml or something like that for describe the your implementation, you should consider that aspect as caching, the correct usage of http ideoms the domain protocol, the meaning of the hypermedia controls and how it describe the your application domain protocol and so on is very complex. Unfortunately or fortunately don't exist an approach as SOAP for describe a rest-ws because you should describe the your behaviour api, the architettural aspect and the application protocol. In fact any api is a resource that is a resource representation in which through the hypermedia controls describe the your application state.

For many details in this discussion I can suggest of read REST in Practis  book that in my opinion is a very interesting and explanatory letter.

I hope that this can help you